# Python 2.7 Convert Letters to Phone Numbers

Tags: python, converters, phone-number, letter

I am trying to complete a code that converts letters into a phone number sequence. What I need is to make for example JeromeB to 537-6632. Also I need the program to cut off the letter translation after the last possible digit. So for example after 1-800-JeromeB even if I write in 1-800-JeromeBrigham it will not code that. The thing is though I do not understand how to implicate that into my code. I do not know understand to cut off the last letter and put in the dash. What I currently have is this

```
alph = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p',\
        'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
num =[2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9]


phone = raw_input('enter phone number ').lower()

s = ""
for index in range(len(phone)):
    if phone[index].isalpha():
        s = s + str(num[alph.index(phone[index])])
    else:
        s = s + phone[index]
print s
```

Comment: Try using a dictionary. I'm too sleepy to test out my answer. But you can easily do this using a dictionary. But why are you entering '1-800-JeromeBrigham', when you specifically ask for 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'?

Comment: you are right i'm sleepy as well hahaha. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# define a dictionary
alph_num_dict = {'a': '2', 'b': '2', 'c': '2',\
                 'd': '3', 'e': '3', 'f': '3',\
                 'g': '4', 'h': '4', 'i': '4',\
                 'j': '5', 'k': '5', 'l': '5',\
                 'm': '6', 'n': '6', 'o': '6',\
                 'p': '7', 'q': '7', 'r': '7', 's': '7',\
                 'u': '8', 'w': '9', 'v': '8',\
                 'w': '9', 'x': '9', 'y': '9', 'z': '9'}
```

**updated**: Cut off chars which follow 7th char, and insert dash in the 4th place

```
# define a generator for converting string and cutting off it
def alph_to_num(phone):
    for index in range(len(phone)):
        if index >= 7:
            return

        if index == 4:
            yield '-'

        p = phone[index]

        if p in alph_num_dict:
            yield alph_num_dict[p]
        else:
            yield p
```

**updated**: Enter "end" for termination

```
# get input and join all converted char from generator
while True:
    phone = raw_input('enter phone number in the format xxxxxxx, or enter "end" for termination ').lower()

    if phone == 'end':
        break

    print ''.join(list(alph_to_num(phone)))
```

**input**: JeromeBrigham

**output**: 5376-632

Comment: thank you this works. is there any the program could input dashes on its own without prompting the user to do so. like if the user inputted NYGBEST it would be xxx-xxxx.

Comment: im trying to remove the prompt asking the user to input the number in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx. i want the code to put in the dashes for the user everything else is perfect.

Comment: Then at least we can restrict the number of user input characters ?

Comment: @d-coder okay so lets restrict it to 10. how do we go about making the code input dashes. if the user were to type in JeromeB it would just plug out xxx-xxxx.

Comment: @Andrew so you want this?

**input**: 1-800-JeromeBrigham
**output**: 1-800-537-6632

Comment: yes and even if the user does not input the first four numbers the dashes would still be including. input- JeromeBA output - 537-6632.

Comment: But you want to cut off extra chars. Like @d-coder said, we need restriction or limited format. If not, how do we know the extra chars are chars follow the 7th char or the 13rd char?

Comment: true i made a severe miscalculation. i guess the lack of sleep is finally getting to me haha. so i actually need it cut off after the seventh number and need a dash after the third. so never mind the 13. I just need the max digits being seven excluding the dash. how must i make it so the code automatically inputs the dash after the third number?

Comment: perfection! i'm sorry i just had one more question. i thought i could do this myself but i found myself forgetting how to add an option to end the loop. For example: the user could type End and the program would thus end the loop.

Comment: @Andrew Check the string (phone) every time you get a new one. if it is the magic word for termination, then break.

Comment: so where exactly would i input the break and change the magic word for termination?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a fixed `range(7)` instead of `range(len(phone))` if you want to always output 7 characters (and raise an error otherwise).

As for the dashes, just check the current index.  If it's 3, add a dash.

Comment: is there any way i could have it just cut off and the letters not mattering instead of an error. Also how would i go about changing the current index?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary with alphas as keys and the corresponding numbers as values, then just iterate the first 10 indexes

```
phone = {'A' : 2, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 2, 'D' : 3, ....}

number = input("Enter a phone number")
counter = 1
for index in number:
  if counter < 10:
    print phone[number]
  counter += 1
```

You can also get a substring of the input

```
number[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use fixed length, and this is so not Pythonic, below is a more elegant rewrite

```
# please complete this map
phone_map = {'a':'2','b':'2','c':'2','d':'3','e':'3','f':'3'} 
"".join([ phone_map[digit] if digit.isalpha() else digit for digit in "abc123abc"])
```

Comment: so i would just have to replace my variable and add this?

Comment: because im not understanding

Answer (score 0):

There is a `string.maketrans` function that generates a 1:1 translation mapping, and calling `translate` on a string and passing this mapping will translate a string in one step.  Example:

```
import string
import re

# This builds the 1:1 mapping.  The two strings must be the same length.
convert = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase,'22233344455566677778889999')

# Ask for and validate a phone number that may contain numbers or letters.
# Allows for more than four final digits.
while True:
    phone = raw_input('Enter phone number in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx: ').lower()
    if re.match(r'(?i)[a-z0-9]{3}-[a-z0-9]{3}-[a-z0-9]{4,}',phone):
        break
    print 'invalid format, try again.'

# Perform the translation according to the conversion mapping.
phone = phone.translate(convert)

# print the translated string, but truncate.
print phone[:12]
```

Output:

```
Enter phone number in the format xxx-xxx-xxxx: 123-abc-defgHIJK
123-222-3334
```

Comment: when i test this out i still get extra digits. since i made a mistake about asking for the format in xxx-xxx-xxxx. is there a way i could incorporate automatic dashes in the code without asking the user to input it themselves.

Comment: How did you get extra digits?  It truncates at 12 places and the two hyphens are required, so should always have 10 digits.

Comment: You could just require input to be length 10 or more and add the hyphens yourself with `print '{}-{}-{}'.format(phone[:3],phone[3:6],phone[6:10])`.

Comment: when i input the code i tested it out and the truncating did not work for some reason.